# Closing modal pop-up after user clicks "Like"

Tags: facebook-like

Our site pops up a modal javascript/jquery dialog, which requires the user to either close or "Like" on facebook to proceed. We are using the HTML5 version of the "Like" code.

The "Close" works fine, but how do I get the dialog to close when the user clicks on "Like"?

The actual "Like" button is provided by Facebook in an IFrame, and I haven't been able to get to it via JavaScript yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to the `edge.create` FB JS event (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) and close your popup once you receive that.  However, you will run into issues because after a like, Facebook also likes to put up a dialog that allows the liker to post a link to their wall about it. So you might accidentally hide that one by closing your dialog too early.

Comment: Note that `edge.create` is no longer supported per here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604171/like-fb-page-doesnt-fire-edge-create-event-after-confirming

Answer (score 0):

First of all check that the following code implemented:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=261463080590982";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then just do the following:

```
<script>
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
close_function()
});
</script>
```

Where close_funciton() is the same function what you call in normal close.

More information about this feature: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

If you have more like button in same page with different "function", that's fun.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to show it at all
you can use the CSS code below

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment{
  position: absolute;
}

.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget iframe.fb_ltr {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The classes are not found in Facebook frame.

Comment: If you look closely, the answer was posted in 2012, pretty sure this solution does not work anymore. Would love if you could change your vote. It's still a valid answer, but from 2012.

Comment: Yeah, I know but it's not a definitive solution. And I think the people here want a final solution. No one wants something that to stop after a while.