# Like FB page doesn't fire edge.create event after confirming

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

The following codes have worked before but not now. Since FB added the confirm box when liking a page, the edge.create was no more fired after confirming.

```
    <div class="fb-page" data-href="{{ $fbPageUrl }}" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
                FB.init({
                    appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    xfbml      : true,
                    version    : 'v2.9'
                });

                FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
                    alert('Fired!');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please go to this link to get the code for Facebook like button https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a bug from the new Facebook's update. You can search for the issue here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs, also can post a new bug if it hasn't been reported yet

Answer (score 5):

You can no longer subscribe to `edge.create`. At this time (04/2018) it is still in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.12), but it is deprecated and to be fully removed in the near future.

By design, there is no way for a third party application to know when the [Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) is clicked.

**You will need to design your app in a way that does not require you to know when the Facebook Like button provided in the iframe is clicked.**

Referencing this [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1971290573187766/):

> The edge.create event is deprecated (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs/), so the engineers have decided not to fix it for this case since it will be taken out completely in the future api release.

And from [this one](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/113963662604765/):

> I understand that it's important to you, but unfortunately we did the deprecate on purpose due to policy issue.

> Developers are not supposed to check the user press any more.

Answer (score 2):

> These Events will no longer be accessible. As an alternative, you can use our Webhooks and be notified every time someone likes one of your Facebook Pages.

[This is the webhooks endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/#feed)

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/)

Answer (score 0):

Working solution until now:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Facebook Like Button</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({appId: '1906177386133148', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        FB.Event.subscribe("edge.create", function (targetUrl) {
            console.log('edge.create');
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe("edge.remove", function (targetUrl) {
            console.log('edge.remove');
        });
    };
    (function () {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
<fb:like></fb:like>
</body>
</html>
```